# Return result after deferred execution in jQuery plugin without callback function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have plugin, which has return direction (like: top, left..) of which side you enter the element. The problem is - one function inside plugin executed after some timeout, so when i call plugin - obviously it return me undefined.

```
;(function($){
  jQuery.fn.myplugin = function(options){

    var somefunction = function(){
        setTimeout(function(elem, e){
            return elem * e; // some action, no matter
        }, 500)              // the important thing - it's executed after plugin returned undefined
    }

    return someFunction;

  };
})(jQuery);
```

Is it possible to resolve this without using callback function, or it is necessary in this case?

I'd like to user plugin like

```
var direction = $('elem').myplugin();
```

but with callback this should be

```
$('elem').myplugin({
    callback: function(direction){
        // so i got direction here
    }
})
```

looks not so pretty anymore

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  Javascript can't do what you're asking.

Comment: I am writing plugin to determine which side you have enter or leave the element (mouseenter, mouseleave events). And inside function of determining leave direction I bind once to WINDOW mousemove event, to get cursor coordinates. And looks like this bind executes few milliseconds later after plugin has return empty result.

I will use callbacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is asynchronous, so your code does not know when your function completes, and cannot wait till the end of the execution of your function. Therefore it is not possible to wait for the code to complete and return the result.

To avoid the requirement of a callback function, you will have to avoid asynchronous code (avoid setTimeout). Otherwise, you will need a callback function

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get around using a callback function, that is the nature of `setTimeout` and asynchronous programming in general. It is a good thing, do not be deterred if it does not seem as "pretty".

But in the way of prettiness, there is no need to define the callback *inside* the plugin call:

```
// "driver" code
$('elem').myplugin({
  callback: myApplicationCallback //or desired name
});

// your application logic code
function myApplicationCallback(direction) {
  // do work
}
```

clean!